# Netsuite Saved Transaction Search - Get summary fields in results

Tags: search, netsuite

I'm trying to create a saved search that will give me the subtotal as seen in the summary field on a Netsuite transaction.  This is usually very doable but in this case, when I do a sum on the amount of items sold, it is giving me the subtotal minus the coupon discount.  As you can see in the screen grabs, the Subtotal field has an id of 'subtotal' but that isn't in the list of choices and if I try to pull that field into a formula, I get an error that the field does not exist.

Netsuite Summary Block:

[image: Netsuite Summary Block]

Netsuite Subtotal Field:

[image: Netsuite Subtotal Field]

Netsuite Discount Field:

[image: Netsuite Discount Field]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't pull these fields via an API request, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In a Netsuite's saved search, there is not a single field to access subtotal amount.
Instead, add a Formula(Currency) column in the search as:-

```
Formula (Currency) = 
nvl({totalamount},0)- 
nvl({discountamount},0)- 
nvl({taxtotal},0)- 
nvl({shippingamount},0)
```

This calculates the subtotal as shown in the summary section of a transaction.

reference:-
[SuiteAnswer ID: 76161](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/76161/kw/subtotal%20in%20saved%20search)